# i dont understand what "protected void Page_Load" is

Tags: c#, void, protected

im learning computer science and in all my cs files i have that line of code that i do not understand the purpose for...i understood that it waits for the page to load or something but what is void and protected all about?

```
protected void Page_Load
```

is a the piece of code

Comment: If it's a line of code, presumably it has a specific language. You may want to add a tag specifying that :-)

Comment: I tagged it c#, since your said you "cs" files. That isn't the whole line, is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`protected` is an access modifier and it means that access is limited to the containing class or types derived from the containing class.

`void` is the return type of the method and it means it it does not return anything.

As mentioned by other `Page_Load`re  is the event method triggered when the current page is  is loaded so this method doesn't return anything as well does need to be accessed by other classes other than the class it resides. (sometimes however you may need to change this modifier).

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx) may have a general look about access modifiers

Answer (score 1):

It's basically a method that will get called once the page has loaded.  'Protected' means that it's visible from within the class and any classes that inherits it, 'void' means it has no return value, and 'Page_Load' is the name of the method.

This method will, most probably, be handling an 'event' that gets fired once the page has loaded and this occurs when all the controls on the page have been created.